# MBR Lost after shrinking Active Partition

Tags: 12.04, mount, mbr, boot-repair

I've got a serious issue with MBR.

Initially got Windows 7 Up on my machine.
I shrinked the active partition to create space for installing ubuntu. I formatted the new available space. Now i simply cannot boot to my Windows 7. So, plugged into Ubuntu LIVE USB drive, tried to access partitions and it says:

> Unable to mount System: **Adding read ACL for uid 999 to `/media/ubuntu' failed: Operation not supported**

Didn't loose hope, so tried Boot-Repair, Now simply stuck at FreeDos screen at bootup

Please find Boot Info Below:

> http://paste.ubuntu.com/5652026/

Any Help much appreciated!
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

No worries people!
Found the solution by myself like all the time..

Following are steps to recover/fix your MBR in such case:

1. Create Windows 7 Bootable USB Using Windows 7 USB/DVD Tool ([link to
   download](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool))
2. Boot using this USB Disc
3. When the setup shows partitions, press **Shift+F10**
4. Type "bootrec /fixBoot", enter
5. Type "bootrec /fixMbr", enter
6. Restart and boot without USB, Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

In this case you have to fix your MBR. put your windows installation disc to you dvd rom and restart and boot your computer through Windows DVD and repair your OS. now then try to install Ubuntu
Learn more about [MBR](http://techmans.blogspot.com/2014/05/master-boot-record-mbr-globally-unique.html)